# What are some synonyms for "capturing" in photography?

Tags: synonyms

In the context of photography what are some synonyms for "capturing". As in capturing a scene, an event, a moment, etc.  My search [in a thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/capture) did not reveal anything I would consider applicable. I am trying to avoid repetition of the same word.

Comment: What is wrong with "capturing", or simply "photographing"

Comment: For an action shot you might say "freeze".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context and the exact impression that is desired.

- One might simply use "photograph" as a verb:

  > He photographed Mt Fuji.
- One can use "took", short for "took a picture of" but be careful that it is not confused with the more commone meang of took that is ":stole" or carried away".

  > He took Eliza Shallcross in her role as Jane Eyre.
- In some cases one might used "memorialized".

  > She memorialized the occasion in a famous photo.
- One might use "recorded" when looking for a relatively neutral term

  > They recorded the event using a 35 mm camera.
- To emphasize that the image has been well-known over a long time, one might use "immortalized".

  > The excitement felt at the end of WWII was immortalized in this famous photo of a young woman kissing a sailor on the streets of New York.
- One might use "fix".

  > She fixed the moment the plane crashed in ehr award-winning photo.

Each of these has its merits, but none are in my view generally better than "captured".  One or another may be best in a particular context.

Comment: There's also 'shot' [with similar caveat to 'took'], or 'snapped'; & i've heard young photographers using 'clicked' [which doesn't go down so well with us old folks;)